# Windows 10 composer freeze

Tags: php, windows, composer-php

I have problems with composer on Windows 10. I am using xampp server with PHP 7.1.23 and composer version 1.7.3. I can see both in cmd - `php -v` and `composer -V`. The problem is that when I run a command with composer it just freezes and nothing happens after that. For example:

running - composer global require laravel/installer
leads to this  - Changed current directory to C:/Users/userName/AppData/Roaming/Composer

And nothing changes for hours. It's the same for composer update/install in specific project.

What I tried:

1. Reinstall composer and xampp with and without avast turned on.
2. Changed system paths for composer/php
3. composer diagnose - everything is ok
4. composer clear-cache
5. Installed xampp with php version 7.2
6. Run cmd like administrator

Nothing changed. Could you please give me some advice where I should look for that problem?

**UPDATE:**

*It seems like the problem is with composer last version 1.7.3. I replaced the phar file in C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin with 1.7.2 phar file which you can download from https://getcomposer.org/download/, just scroll down to the bottom of the page.*

Comment: When Composer starts acting weird it can also help to reinstall using the Windows installer, which takes care of fixing stuff like settings or PATH.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Hi, yes I did that couple of times and it didn't help.

Comment: You can also use `-vvv` to figure out what step it's freezing at.